# Know the directory/source to shortcut of file

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably a rare question - is there any way programmatically through VBA to get access to the directory of not the Excel file itself, but the shortcut that opened it?

Comment: No. There's no link between the two and `Command` returns nothing relevant.

Comment: A shortcut could be anyplace.  So you might search the entire environment and see if you find a shortcut file that points to the Excel file.  But you'd have no way of knowing if a particular shortcut (there could be many) was the one that actually opened the file.

Comment: You could edit the shortcut so that it passed a variable to excel and then query that variable. So if you had many shortcuts and wanted to know which was used that would work - but if excel was started via a "run" command or via a command window or shell you'd fail.

Comment: That's a cool idea! How do I do that?